# Populating dropdown from ajax call php

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to change the contents of the drop down based on the value of the first one.

Unfortunately I don't get any errors to see why its not working.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var town_id = 0;
    $("towns").change(function() {
        townid = $('#town').val();
        $("suburbs").load(
            "/assets/php/suburbs.php", {
                town_id: townid
            });
    });

});
```

Here is the php file.

```
<?php

$town_id = $_POST['town_id'];

use Mds\Collivery;

$collivery = new Collivery();

$suburbs = $collivery->getSuburbs($town_id);

foreach ($suburbs as $key => $suburb) {
    echo "<option value='";
    echo $key;
    echo "'>";
    echo $suburb;
    echo "</option>";
}
```

However it unfortunately isnt working. any idea of where i went wrong?

//Edit

As requested

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="towns">Select Town:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="towns">
    @foreach ($towns as $key => $town)
    <option value="{{$key}}">{{$town}}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="suburb">Select Suburb:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="suburb">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Your are getting $_POST['town_id'] ?

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in chrome dev tools to see what response is being returned from the ajax call?

Comment: `$("towns").change()`.. do you actually have an element called `<towns>`? Or do you mean to query it by id `$("#towns").change()` or by class `$(".towns").change()`? My guess would be that you want to do `$("#town")`, since that's what you're pulling the value from. The same goes for `$("suburbs").load()`.

Comment: I have a dropdown for towns yes and a dropdown for suburbs that i want it to populate.

Comment: and you are not specified the full url

Comment: so your path may be incorrect

Comment: @JohnBell i have just looked but i dont see any network traffic for the ajax call at all. So that means the ajax call isnt actually activiting?

Comment: I don't think you quite understood my previous comment. Please show us the HTML as well (specifically the towns and suburbs drop downs). Also, this: `var town_id = 0;` is pretty useless since you don't ever use the `town_id` variable in your code.

Comment: change $("towns") to $("#towns"), $("suburbs") to $("#suburbs"),townid = $('#town').val(); to townid = $(this).val();

Comment: @afsalc thanks for the changes, i have done these changes with still no success.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i edited the code with what you have requested. i have taked the 'var town_id = 0;' out and just simply added 'var townid = $(this).val();'

Comment: Your update made it even more confusing. You have `$("towns")` and `$("suburbs")` but you don't have any HTML-elements at all that refer to those names in any way at all (element name, form name, id or class). What do you expect `$("towns")` and `$("suburbs")` to actually do? jQuery might do some magic for you, but it can't read your mind.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sorry i need to go sleep because brain is fried.

But okay what i am trying to do, 

i am using a shipping api for an online store. Now the api requires a town_id to be passed through to retrieve a suburb list.

Once I have the suburb I can generate the cost of the Shipping.

So i have the Towns dropdown working with a value of each town_id, then once an item is selected. the dropdown for the suburb list is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var town_id = $('#town').val();
    $("#towns").on('change', function() {
        $("#suburbs").load(
            "/assets/php/suburbs.php", {
                town_id: town_id
            });
    });

});
```

I gave in after reading the comments on your post. I implore you to study this code and see the differences I have made to make it work, rather than copy and paste.